# How do I organise media queries CSS files?

Tags: css, media-queries

For the sake of simplicity, lets say that I have two pages on my site, a landing page and a product page. Both pages have 3 break points using media queries. As it stands I have a `master.css` file and 3 break point `.css` for each page.

It is feeling a bit repetitive copying and pasting the header, footer, navigation buttons over and over again. As I am new to this I don't know the correct "method" for structuring my files.

Should I continue to stick with this method or should I separate my header, footer and nav css into separate css docs and contain all the break points for them in that same place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `master.css` file should really include all of the `CSS` that will be applied throughout your base layout.

Take for example the following HTML layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title - My Webpage</title>

        <link href="css/master.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
        <div id='container'>
            <p>Page Content</p>
         </div>
         <div id="footer">
             &copy; Copyright 2014 by YOU.
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Although some pages might have a special sidebar or maybe some page-specific vertical navigation, the main layout like the page title, container, etc. should be styled in a shared external stylesheet including your media queries. This really is personal preference, but you can [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) the other external stylesheets into your `master.css` or you can have multiple stylesheets included in your `<head`> section.  Then, on the pages that have a special component, like a sidebar, you include your `sidebar.css` or whatever `.css`.

As for the duplication of the markup, if you're going to be using static markup files (ie `.html`) then you'll need to keep duplicating it for every new page. Another option however, is to use a [template engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system).

Basically, a template engine allows you to move reusable layouts into separate files for reuse. Here is a basic example using [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html), a PHP Template engine.

**layout.html.twig**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
            <!-- master css and js to be shared on the base layout -->
            <link href="css/master.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="js/script.js"></script>

            <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Webpage</title>
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{% block heading}{% endblock %}</h1>
        <div id='container'>
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
         </div>
         <div id="footer">
             {% block footer %}
                  &copy; Copyright 2014 by YOU.
             {% endblock %}
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is going to be the shared layout. We are going to extend this layout in our front-facing pages.

**product.html.twig**:

```
<!--here we are extending our base layout, so we don't have to duplicate the static layout -->
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
{% block head %}
    <!-- parent() is going to extract all of the stuff in our layout in the 'head' block -->
    {{ parent() }}

    <!-- this is our page specific code in our head -->
    <style type="text/css">
        .important { color: #336699; }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
{% block heading %}Hello, World! {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <p class="important">
        Welcome to my awesome homepage.
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

Now if we visit our products page, we'll see the main layout with our page specific titles, styles, content, etc inserted in the blocks we've defined.

<sub>To see this example in more detail, visit the [Twig Documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#template-inheritance).</sub>

So, by using a template engine we've done two awesome things:

1. Eliminated the need of duplicating static markup.
2. Created a concrete implementation of our design that can be easily reused and extended.

Keep in mind that there is some overhead for using an option like this, so for very simple websites with only a few pages it might be better to just use static markup.

Comment: Once this has been designed, Im sending it of to a developer to put it into magento. Am I write in thinking magento also uses "blocks" system?

EDIT: This is an amazing answer! @Carrie Kendall

Comment: I'm not familiar with Magento but a lot of e-commerce applications use theming similar to this. But regardless of the syntax and implementation the idea stays the same, reusable code is separated from page-specific code.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the complexity of the site. In your case, if you have just a couple of pages, it is better to create a single stylesheet containing all the styles and the Media Queries. You can scope them or with a modular approach (see below) or by adding a class to each page and applying styles using descendant selectors.

An example of modular approach would be:

```
<div class="Product">
  <div class="Product-image">..</div>
  <p class="Product-description">...</p>
</div>
```

and in your stylesheet:

```
.Product { ... }
.Product-image { ... }
.Product-description { ... }
```

**EDIT:** I advice you to give a read to [this article](http://css-tricks.com/one-two-three)

Comment: Hi thanks for responding! it was just for simplicity that I said two pages, there will be 15, give or take a few in total.

Comment: See the edit. Also, are you using pure-static pages?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to adopt SASS or another similar css utility (LESS, Stylus, etc..) to manage your project structure in a better way.

For example i usually have a main *screen.scss* file with all the @imports and if i have some code related (for example) to the header i write the default behaviour in a file named *header.scss* and all the responsive code in a file named *header_mq.scss*

In this way you can structure your app's css and if a component isn't used in a page you can simply avoid to import the block for that particular page.

I also suggest to read this book http://smacss.com/